# Process/thread information which accessing the file

Tags: multithreading, process, permission-denied

I was looking if there exists a program in c/c++ which gives the process and thread information which access files within a given folder. Actually when my application is running all of sudden I am getting the **"Reason = 13 (Permission denied)"** for **fopen()** method call. I have tried googling this, but I didn't get relevant information. There is a chance of other applications also access the file. So I would like to log the process and thread information when I got the above mentioned error. I am unaware of anything which does this and would like to know if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you don't have permissions to access the file. See [Traditional Unix permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions)
 for more details.

This error is not related to the file being used by other processes.